# How to convert \tableofcontents from interfaces-tocloft to titletoc package?

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

I'm trying to remove the `interfaces-tocloft` package from my documents, it causes problems in some and loads packages that I do not want in some occasions, so I've tried using `titletoc` (which is something more familiar to me that `tocloft`), but I can not get the same result.
This is my example file using the `interfaces-tocloft` package:

```
% toctest.tex
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[sf,bf,compact,medium,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,multicol,hyperref,blindtext}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{interfaces-tocloft}

% Config hyperref
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor          = blue!50,
   colorlinks         = true,%
   }

% Table of contents
\def\rulecolor{\color{gray}}
\tocsetup{%
title=Contents\quad{\rulecolor\leaders\vrule height4.4pt depth-4pt\hfill\null},
 title/after= \vspace{3pt},
 title/font= \sffamily\bfseries\Large,%
 title/top=10pt,%
 title/bottom=0pt,%
 twocolumns,
 section/skip=4pt plus2pt minus2pt,%
 subsection/skip=0pt plus2pt minus2pt,
 section/leaders,section/dotsep,%
 after=\vspace{-3pt}\noindent{\rulecolor\hrule height4.4pt depth-4pt\relax},
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{A introduction subsection I}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{A introduction subsection II}
\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Other Section}
\subsection{A other subsection I}
\subsection{A other subsection II}
\lipsum[21-28]
\subsection{A other subsection II}
\lipsum[29-36]
\section{New Section}
\subsection{A New subsection I}
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection I}
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection II}
\lipsum[37-39]
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection I}
\lipsum[40-42]
\section{Final Section} 
\subsection{A Final subsection I}
\lipsum[43-45]
\subsubsection{A Final subsubsection II}
\lipsum[46-48]
\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:
[image: tocloft-OK]

This is my attempt using the `titletoc` package:

```
% toctest.tex
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[sf,bf,compact,medium,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,multicol,hyperref,blindtext}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{interfaces-tocloft}

% Config hyperref
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor          = blue!50,
   colorlinks         = true,%
   }

\titlecontents{section}[15pt]{\addvspace{1em}\bfseries}%
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{15pt}}%
    {}% numberless
    {\hspace{0.25em}\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]%

\titlecontents{subsection}[30pt]{}%
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{15pt}}% numbered
    {}% numberless
    {\hspace{0.25em}\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]%

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[45pt]{}%
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{15pt}}% numbered 
    {}% numberless
    {\hspace{0.25em}\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]

% Table of contents
\def\rulecolor{\color{gray}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\begingroup%
\noindent{\sffamily\bfseries\Large\contentsname\quad\rulecolor\leaders\vrule height4.4pt depth-4pt\hfill}\null%
\vspace*{-10pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt}%
 \begin{multicols}{2}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
\end{multicols}%
\vspace*{-10pt}
\rulecolor\hrule height4.4pt depth-4pt\relax\null%
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{A introduction subsection I}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{A introduction subsection II}
\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Other Section}
\subsection{A other subsection I}
\subsection{A other subsection II}
\lipsum[21-28]
\subsection{A other subsection II}
\lipsum[29-36]
\section{New Section}
\subsection{A New subsection I}
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection I}
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection II}
\lipsum[37-39]
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection I}
\lipsum[40-42]
\section{Final Section} 
\subsection{A Final subsection I}
\lipsum[43-45]
\subsubsection{A Final subsubsection II}
\lipsum[46-48]
\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:
[image: titletoc-NotOK]

I can not find the right measures to make it look appropriate (therefore I have not added `numberless` sections). The idea is to look like this:

```
1 Section ......................
  1.1 Subsection I .............
      1.1.1 Subsubsection I ....
      1.1.2 Subsubsection II ...
      1.1.3 Subsubsection III ..
```

How can I achieve this using `titletoc`?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

To get this just requires the following small tweak of your code for `subsubsection`s:

```
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[45pt]{}%
    {\hspace{1.00em}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{25pt}}% numbered
    {}% numberless
    {\hspace{0.25em}\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]
```

For completeness, here is the full code:

```
% toctest.tex
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage[sf,bf,compact,medium,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,multicol,hyperref,blindtext}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{interfaces-tocloft}

% Config hyperref
\hypersetup{
   linkcolor          = blue!50,
   colorlinks         = true,%
   }

\titlecontents{section}[15pt]{\addvspace{1em}\bfseries}%
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{15pt}}%
    {}% numberless
    {\hspace{0.25em}\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]%

\titlecontents{subsection}[30pt]{}%
    {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{15pt}}% numbered
    {}% numberless
    {\hspace{0.25em}\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]%

\titlecontents{subsubsection}[45pt]{}%
    {\hspace{1.00em}\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{25pt}}% numbered
    {}% numberless
    {\hspace{0.25em}\titlerule*[6pt]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]

% Table of contents
\def\rulecolor{\color{gray}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\begingroup%
\noindent{\sffamily\bfseries\Large\contentsname\quad\rulecolor\leaders\vrule height4.4pt depth-4pt\hfill}\null%
\vspace*{-10pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{10pt}%
 \begin{multicols}{2}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
\end{multicols}%
\vspace*{-10pt}
\rulecolor\hrule height4.4pt depth-4pt\relax\null%
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{A introduction subsection I}
\lipsum[1-10]
\subsection{A introduction subsection II}
\lipsum[11-20]
\section{Other Section}
\subsection{A other subsection I}
\subsection{A other subsection II}
\lipsum[21-28]
\subsection{A other subsection II}
\lipsum[29-36]
\section{New Section}
\subsection{A New subsection I}
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection I}
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection II}
\lipsum[37-39]
\subsubsection{A New subsubsection I}
\lipsum[40-42]
\section{Final Section}
\subsection{A Final subsection I}
\lipsum[43-45]
\subsubsection{A Final subsubsection II}
\lipsum[46-48]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect, I found a related answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226367/7832) using `\contentspush` and `\mbox` that I think is the best for this case. Greetings and thanks